# requests module produces some corrupted file when I attempt to download a pdf file from a link

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to download [a pdf file](https://colwood.civicweb.net/filepro/document/197721/RZ-22-012.pdf?handle=99B7BEBB4DFB4EB987761DA873019A6D) from a link using requests module but the script produces some corrupted file.
When the download appears to be complete and I try to open it manually, I get the error 'Failed to load PDF content'.

However, when I use [another link](https://colwood.civicweb.net/document/195300/) from the same site, the script can download it smoothly.

I'm using this script to download the file:

```
import requests

link = 'https://colwood.civicweb.net/filepro/document/197721/RZ-22-012.pdf?handle=99B7BEBB4DFB4EB987761DA873019A6D'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
with open("demo.pdf","wb") as f:
    for data in res.iter_content(1024):
        if data:
            f.write(data)
```

How can I download the pdf file from the link within the script using requests module?

Comment: Have you tried downloading manually (i.e., without using `requests`)?  Does the first link still give a corrupted file?

Comment: When I manually download the file, everything goes well.